# Regexp: How to accept both single and double quotes but not together

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

How can I match this

```
<a href="logout.html">Logout</a>
```

**And** this

```
<a href='logout.html'>Logout</a>
```

EDIT (and capture *logout.html* and *logout*)

But **not** this :

```
<a href="'.$var.'">'.$another_var.'</a>
```

Right now I have this

```
"^.*<a.*href=\"\\([^\"]+\\)\"[^>]+>\\([^<]+\\)</a>"
```

But it only matches double quotes, and takes the variable links as well...

Comment: (Yes, this is Emacs regexp syntax (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) ; I would like the answer to use it but if not I'll adapt it myself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workable/safer version of Avinash Raj's approach to the quoting issue is:

`<a .*?\bhref=\(['"]\)[^'"]*\1.*?>.*?</a>`

As a string:

`"<a .*?\\bhref=\\(['\"]\\)[^'\"]*\\1.*?>.*?</a>"`

n.b. Don't use greedy operators where it's not safe to do so! e.g.: `<a.*href` is a rather bad idea.

Edit: So it turns out you only want the URL and link text from the match, in which case you would add additional groups around those:

`"<a .*?\\bhref=\\(['\"]\\)\\([^'\"]*\\)\\1.*?>\\(.*?\\)</a>"`

and then ask for the strings matched by groups 2 & 3.

In elisp, you would most likely use `(match-string 2)` & `(match-string 3)`, but it depends on how you are using the regexp.

Note also that regexps *can't* match balanced expressions, so they can't always give a perfect solution in this sort of situation, and you are dependent on assumptions about the data you are processing. If your URL were to contain an quote, this regexp would fail.

Of course elisp in general has plenty of support for dealing with balanced expressions, so you might instead match the element in a more basic form, and then use `forward-sexp` to move from the opening quote to the closing quote in the more reliable way. Obviously that's out of this question's scope.

Edit 2: Apparently I actually have to demonstrate this.

[image: re-builder]

The only difference between that and my original regexp is the addition of the extra groups, due to your subsequent edit to your question.

Comment: It only captures the link (not the title) but it's close :) +1 for the word boundary operator.

Comment: It should capture the entire `<a ...></a>` element. It certainly covers your examples. I should have provided a string-based version, though. See the edit.

Comment: Using your "string" answer I managed to muster this : `"<a .*href=\\(['\"].*?\\)>\\(.*?\\)</a>"` but How can i tell it 1-To stop after the second (not the last) quote, and 2-to be quote-consistent: To only "close" single-quoted string with single-quotes (and of course only "close" double-quoted string with double-quotes) I hope I'm making myself clear. Your answers (and others BTW) have been very helpful already.

Comment: No, I no longer understand what you're asking for. The regexp given matches the examples given. Your changes (in your comment) have *removed* the part which handles quote consistency. And I don't know what you mean by "stop after the second (not the last) quote", as that doesn't gel with your examples at all.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear : I mean that now it's matching `'this"` and even `'this' and this too"`. Two problems : Consistency (`'this"` should not match) and greedyness (`'this' and this too" <= "and this too" shoud not match)

Comment: The regexp in my answer does not have either of those problems.

Comment: Sorry Phils, but yes it does. Try it with my example in an Emacs buffer and M-x `regexp-builder`

Comment: Uh, no. Which version of Emacs are you using?!? My regexp works perfectly with the examples in your question in `re-builder` or otherwise. I'm using a recent build of Emacs from trunk, but the regexp syntax has certainly not changed anytime recently!

Comment: Ah, I see. You are creating 3 groups instead of 2. That is fine by me and yes, you did answer the question. In your first version, only group 1 and 3 were captured, hence my reaction ; thank you phils.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
<a href=["']\w+\.\w+["']>\w+<\/a>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/qQ0yA0/1)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
^.*<a.*href=(['"])[^'"]*\1>[^<]*<\/a>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tM1wX9/1)